# Query for SharePoint 2013 REST search

Tags: rest, caml

I have to site columns (column1, column2) that are also crawled by the search and available as Crawled properties, so I can use them as filters in REST query as well. 
I'm now trying to build the REST query for the search API to return items that matches the following criteria:

```
<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Column1'/><Value Type='DateTime'><Today/></Value></Eq><IsNull><FieldRef Name='Column2' /></IsNull></And></Where></Query></View>
```

I'm unfortunately unable to figure out how this CAML query can be converted into the syntax that's supported by REST search query.
Could someone, please, help me out with this?

Comment: try this tool to build search query https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/